# sql JOINs and COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

Say I have this query

```
 SELECT ft.*, m.*
   FROM forum_topics ft
     INNER JOIN members m ON ft.author = m.id
     WHERE ft.forum =  '$forum'
     ORDER BY ft.lastpost DESC
```

I want to also get a row count in that from the table `forum_replies` where the `id = ft.id`.
How could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your DB implementation this might work:

```
 SELECT ft.*, 
        m.*,
        ( SELECT count(1)  
            FROM forum_replies fr 
           WHERE fr.id = ft.id) AS nr_of_replies 
   FROM forum_topics ft
     INNER JOIN members m ON ft.author = m.id
     WHERE ft.forum =  '$forum'
     ORDER BY ft.lastpost DESC
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ft.*, m.*, fr.ReplyCount
FROM forum_topics ft
INNER JOIN members m ON ft.author = m.id
inner join (
   Select Id, Count(*) as ReplyCount
   from forum_replys 
   group by id
 ) as fr 
 on ft.Id = fr.Id
 WHERE ft.forum =  '$forum'
 ORDER BY ft.lastpost DESC
```